# Retrieve Order Status from MYSQL database based on value entered

Tags: php, javascript, html, forms, onsubmit

I have created a MySQL database, in which one of my tables is "ServiceOrder" The ServiceOrder table will hold data of order than have been placed by customers and the status of these order, e.g. To be started, Started, Quality Assurance, Finished.

So, I have a website, on which I have a form (see below). In the form I want to allow people to enter their order ID's to retrieve the status of their order. Note: the "ServiceOrder" database include the field, orderID and Status (amongst other things which aren't relevant for this).

Here is my HTML form:

```
<form id="form1" name="form1" method="post" action="">
Insert Order Number Here
    <input name="woodingdeantracking" type="text" id="woodingdeantracking" size="40" />
    <input type="submit" name="Track Order" id="Track Order" value="Track Order" />
</form>
```

What I ideally want it to do for now is when a customer enteres an OrderID that exists it will send them to once page, however if the orderID doesnt't exist they get sent to a different poage.

I hope I have been clear. If any other information is required, please let me know, I am very new to this!

Thanks in advance,
Nav

P.S I am open to using Javascript if it is easier for what I am trying to acheieve for the demo, in essence if "ABC" is enetered return sucess page if anything else is enetred return a failure page.

Answer (score 0):

```
   // validate values before manipulating the database

    $sql = "select status from ServiceOrder where orderID = ".mysql_real_escape_string($_POSt['woodingdeantracking']);

    $query = mysql_query($sql);

    $orderDetails = mysql_fetch_row($query);

    if(count($orderDetails) > 0){
    // redirect to success page with order status value
    }else{
    // redirect to error page
    }
```